Geometry nodes - Splines (Curves) Merging Neighbors CW/CCW
I have a star-shape mesh without faces, that I transform into curves using geometry nodes. When "Mesh to Curve" Node is used, it's all split in the center point into separate splines. When I then change spline type to Catmull-Rom, this separation makes problems with how I need the result to look.

Goal of this post is to have all possible pairs of splines, that are neighbors CW or CCW (meaning one spline will be part of 2 splines, one with the spline that is CW and one with spline that is CCW to it).

The colored lines (black, blue, red) are the curves I want as result
My idea: First sort the splines circularly using arctan2 of the vector between first 2 control points of each spline. Then use for loop node to iterate spline count times and merge i and i+1 spline (0 and n-1 as either the last iteration or separately).
Problems: There can be multiple star-shaped meshes inside one object which makes sorting by angle work only if you can separate them based on shared center point (or connection). Also I didn't figure out how to sample positions of just 2 start-points of each spline.
Desired final functionality: Splines are first duplicated once, then shifted in direction of normal (to both sides), then the merging of the neighbors is performed and then points that are farther than 'r' from center are deleted and the face that is the result is filled in. I don't ask of you this part but might be helpful for context (I might have missed something important) and if anyone has some ideas, I'm here all for them.
 
Current state:



Good question: the problem is clear, you mention both X and Y in the XY problem, you show you've done some work, the .blend file is complimentary. BTW, I see a problem with spline reversing logic: when you evaluate at index, this is not an index local to the spline, so the first index on 2nd spline is not 0.



Use Vertex Count to mark all verts that aren't an intersection - if one of these ends up as the start of the spline, reverse that spline.
Also capture indices of vertices - so that you can use the intersection (start of a spline) captured index as a unique index of a cluster. Now you don't need some awkward way to convert position to UIDs, and you can even support overlapping intersections of multiple clusters.
Capture the position at start of the splines, which are the intersections, to be used as a center of a Radial Gradient.
Offset evaluated position by above-captured position, which is the same as if you temporarily moved all intersections to the origin. Using such modified coordinate, the Radial Gradient is a one-node replacement of the arctan2 logic you proposed. I'm reading the angle at the end of the spline, but if you really need this to be 2nd point, you could e.g. subtract Endpoint Selection: 2;0 MINUS Endpoint Selection: 1; 0. Those selections I multiply by the angle, so that I accumulate nothing except for the one point of interest and capture that on all points.
Since the above is saved an all points, it can be interpolated into a spline domain, and in that domain I can sort all elements (all splines) by angle).
Now use Accumulate Field to calculate indices local to each cluster, as well as a size of that cluster needed for wrapping using modulo.
Duplicate Elements, as you suggested.
Split to instances. For the original (Duplicate Index = 0), use the local "In-cluster Index" as group ID. Keep in mind this means clusters reuse instances, i.e. first splines of all clusters end up in the same instance. This breaks the possibility mentioned earlier about overlapping clusters, but the fix to that isn't hard... Now, you want to pair this spline with another, so for Duplicate Index = 1, since this D.Index is added to the Group ID, it will end up with the next ("In-Cluster Index" higher by 1) splines. Unless it's the last spline, in which case the modulo reverts it back to 0.
The end is obvious, in particular the instances can be realized just after "Merge by Distance", as I only used instancing to separate this merging process.
"Scale Elements" is my lazy, imperfect way of moving the points. You may want to scale by very little, compare the direction in which the intersection point moved to its normal and if the dot product is negative, flip the normal, to then just offset by normal.

Result:


Face filling:

